# What is wrong in finding anagram of string in my code? I did it using Hashmap in C programming

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, hashmap, anagram

```
void anagram(char s[],char s1[]){ // Using Hashmap of size 26 (0 - 25)
    int i,H[26]={0};
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
        H[s[i]-97]+=1;           
    }
    for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++){
        H[s1[i]-97]-=1;          
        if(H[s[i]-97]<0){        
            printf("Not anagram\n");
            break;
        }
    }
  }
if(s1[i]=='\0'){        
                printf("Anagram\n");
    
}

int main()
{
  char s[100];
  char s1[100];
  gets(s);
  printf("Enter string 2 for checking anagram :\n");
  gets(s1);
  anagram(s,s1);
}
```

What's wrong with this code? I am getting answer as "Anagram" even for input "cake" and "cane"?
Can anyone explain why it is showing like this

Comment: Maybe `s` and `s1` are not the best names for those variables. They're so similar that you could easily type `s` when you meant `s1`. That's a hint. (I'd probably use `s1` and `s2`, but there are lots of possibilities.)

Comment: Another problem is that your code will claim that `cane` and `can` are anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong with your code :

1. Your function seems to have an incorrect closing "}" before the if statement itself.
2. The not anagram check should be done for the second string, not first. Change `if(H[s[i]-97]<0)` to `if(H[s1[i]-97]<0)`